# At what point is version control needed?

Tags: version-control, versioning, mercurial

I work in embedded systems. Right now, my organization has two full-time programmers and two occasional programmers. It's rare that the same project is worked on by two programmers. All code is stored on a network drive. There are folders for the current production code, another folder for the source for every released version throughout history, and a third folder for active work. We have an automated system (Mercurial being abused) that makes backups of every changed code file in Working every fifteen minutes, so we can revert to previous states.

My question is this: is it worth the trouble to set up a formal versioning system in an environment like this? Why or why not?

Comment: Eh? It sounds as though you have version control, albeit a non-standard implementation of it.

Comment: Right. I suppose I should clarify, at what point would it be worth moving to a standard implementation?

Comment: Do you know why your group does it this way? What problems did it solve and what problems does it cause? Otherwise, there are other questions about the benefits of version control.

Comment: My group does it this way because nobody here knows the benefits of doing it any other way. :) The network drive is the most obvious way to share code between computers. And the version control is to allow a hail-Mary save in case something goes horribly wrong with our working version. Which has happened once or twice.

Comment: @StephenCollings: MainMa's answer tells you a couple of reasons why its better to make *logical* commit groups, with log entries describing what was changed, and an automatic log of who did some specific change, and a guarantee that each commit corresponds to a working build. The only drawback is that you will have to get your team to change their accustomed behaviour to make them work with the version control system as they should. That will probably mean to kick some asses (including your own). Once you have educated your team, the benefits will show up by themselves.

Comment: Trust me, you always need version control, and daily/weekly backups.

Comment: I was playing code golf writing a one liner this morning, and since I was just playing I wasn't using version control. I learned some things, but I wish I had kept a couple of the intermediate revisions. I should have used version control.

Comment: @StephenCollings Probably not the most constructive comment, for which I apologize, but why would you not want a standard implementation? What you're doing right now, is building some sort of version control system yourself. How much time and effort has gone into that during its lifespan? Any standard implementation has oodles more possibilities, is going to be orders of magnitude more robust and will have loads of information and extra tooling available on the internet because so many other people use those standard implementations.

Comment: When you need to ask this question.

Comment: In addition to all of the comments/answers now and to come, working with a version control tool like Git or Mercurial has fundamentally changed my workflow for the better.  And almost all of that benefit (versus SVN or CVS) is due to using Git or Mercurial locally.  I place a heavy onus on anyone *not* using a modern vcs to explain why they do not need it.

Comment: Heck, I use a proper version control system for my personal (so far tiny) hobby projects! About the only situation in which I won't use it is for more or less one-off things that I write, run, and throw away. Anything more than that pretty much deserves a proper VCS in my opinion. Whether you use centralized or distributed (SVN vs Git), manufacturer-specific or generic (TFS vs SVN), and so on, is a matter of taste.

Comment: How much can you afford to lose or forget? You need it that much.

Comment: Always! Version control is always needed even if you will be the only programmer that will ever touch that code. When you are working the project by your self it is best to use Distributed Source Control like "Tortoise HQ" that is what I used when I was only one working on project. This lets me keep up with my own changes and figure out at what time the certain pieces of code broke.

Comment: There is no reason not to use version control.  It does no harm even when it adds no benefits, so why not?

Comment: Lots of comments here just argue as if you had actually *no* system installed, the people seem to read your question title but not your question. I suggest you consider to change the title a little bit, to something like "when does  version control bring real benefits over automatic historic backups on a network folder?"

Comment: What you describe sounds like [Copy folder versioning](http://deviq.com/copy-folder-versioning).  "Real" version control gives you the ability to take a snapshot or even create a branch when you do a release -- much more reliable than a network folder than may get deleted. Also, with a VCS you can create branches so you can do development (possibly on multiple new feature sets concurrently) without corrupting your "trunk" or core -- and you can do commits against those branches meaning you won't lose intermediate work in progress.  In short, the answer is "absolutely".

Comment: Your assumption that it is "trouble" to set up proper version control is problematic; it sounds to me like your hacked-together version control system is a lot more trouble to maintain than the few minutes it would take to set up a proper free or purchased version control system.

Comment: Setting up a version control solution will totally worth the time. It’s what version control tool do – manage different code revisions (active, production, release) and allow you to revert back to any history version when needed. For a small team, you can choose a simple version control tool. If you don’t have resources to manage the server, you can also consider hosting option.

Answer (score 84):

As you describe it, you already have some sort of version control, though currently there are some issues with it compared to a typical version control:

An intentional commit in version control indicates that the developer strongly believes that the current state of the system would build successfully.

(There are exceptions, as suggested by [Jacobm001's comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223027/at-what-point-is-version-control-needed/223028?noredirect=1#comment443727_223028). Indeed, several approaches are possible, and some teams would prefer not trying to make every commit possible to build. One approach is to have nightly builds, given that during the day, the system may receive several commits which don't build.)

Since you don't have commits, your system will often result in a state which doesn't build. This **prevents you from setting Continuous Integration**.

By the way, a distributed version control system has a benefit: one can do local commits as much as needed while bringing the system to a state where it cannot build, and then do a public commit when the system is able to build.

1. Version control lets you **enforce some rules on commit**. For example, for Python files, PEP 8 can be run, preventing the commit if the committed files are not compliant.
2. **Blame** is extremely hard to do with your approach.
3. Exploring what changes were made when, and by who is hard too. Version control **logs**, the list of changed files and **a `diff`** is an excellent way to find exactly what was done.
4. **Any merge would be a pain** (or maybe developers wouldn't even see that their colleagues were modifying the files before they save the changes). You stated that:

   > It's rare that the same project is worked on by two programmers

   Rare doesn't mean never, so merges would occur sooner or later.
5. A backup every fifteen minutes means that **developers may lose up to fifteen minutes of work**. This is always problematic: it's hard to remember exactly what changes were done meanwhile.
6. With source control you can have meaningful commit messages. With backups all you know is that it was x minutes since last backup.

A real version control ensures that you can always revert to the previous commit; this is a huge advantage. Reverting a backup using your system would be slightly more difficult than doing a **one-click rollback**, which you can do in most version control systems. Also, in your system **Branching** is impossible.

There's a better way to do version control, and you should certainly consider changing the way you currently do it. Especially since, like [Eric Lippert mentions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223027/at-what-point-is-version-control-needed/223028?noredirect=1#comment443907_223027), your current system is probably a lot more painful to maintain than any common version control system is. Having a Git or Mercurial repository on a network drive is pretty easy for example.

***Note:*** Even if you switch to a common version control system, you should still have a daily/weekly backup of the repositories. If you're using a distributed system it's less important though, since then every developer's working copy is also a backup.

Comment: I'll bet with this team, if two devs worked on the same file, one of the files would get thrown in the trash. "Hey, you didn't make a lot of changes did you? I really need to keep mine."

Comment: Merges also happen with the solo developer when the developer wants to go back to some previous point (a release), fix a bug in production, and then later move the longer living feature code into production.

Comment: A slight bit of semantics... Not all commits require that the application will build properly.  Often it's far from truth.  Commits to the main branch *should* usually build, but most people I know will often commit to a specific branch anythime they feel something meaningful was accomplished.  Then they have records and more detailed (meaningful) differences that can be reversed.

Comment: @Jacobm001 it depends on the policy of the branch.  Branch on Incompatible Policy is a common "when to branch" pattern.  See http://www.bradapp.com/acme/branching/branch-creation.html#PolicyBranch -- if the branch has the policy of "all commits are good" and you want to check in work in progress, branch.

Comment: This does not actually answer the OP's question, only addresses differences between their way of doing version control and the conventional way...

Answer (score 49):

Just my personal view: Version control is useful for anything that takes me more than half a day or that involves a lot of trial and error – or both, of course. If it involves two or more people who are not using the same keyboard and monitor all the time, it is essential.

The cost of using a formal versioning system, beyond the initial learning curve, is negligible. Initializing a repo? Two seconds. Adding files? One second. Being able to go back to what I tried this morning and discuss what I discarded with my colleague? Worth hours or days, easily.

Comment: Initializing a repo? Two seconds. Adding files? One second. Being able to go back to a commit before I f***ed everything up? Priceless.

Comment: Agree. I put my _homework_ in version control.

Answer (score 38):

Version control was always needed, even before you hacked together your "but, we backup really often!" kludge.

Version control lets you publish those changes across files that belong to a logical function as a unit. If you need to review "what was necessary for case-insensitive sorting in that mask?", it tells you all relevant changes and suppresses the irrelevant ones.

Good version control keeps track of file names, metadata, and of the provenance of every individual line of code.

Version control lets you tag all changes with the reason you made them.

Version control is not about allowing more than one person to work together. It is about guaranteeing the historical record of your codebase. Secure in the knowledge that you cannot lose anything, or even forget when you did it and how, you are free to refactor, invent and create without fear. And you don't know what fearlessness is before you've experienced it.

Comment: Agreed. Kind of reminds me of this blog post I read some time ago: http://cam.ly/blog/2010/12/code-fearlessly/

Comment: I just experienced a good example of the fearlessness yesterday.  I wasn't sure about a choice I was making, so just created branches and implemented the idea and an alternative.  I was free to compare multiple solutions and then choose the best path.   I probably wouldn't have tried this if I had to jump through the hoops of a hackier solution than git or another VCS.

Answer (score 15):

There is a great deal of value in using version control even as an individual developer and it could be quite a bit simpler than the backup/file copy based system you have now.

- Right now, you have the ability to get to older version of the code, but how do you find the version you want?
- Just the ability to do a diff between revisions will be very valuable.  Integration with development tools is another benefit you aren't getting from you current tools.
- Another substantial benefit is the ability to branch, and experiment with new features or designs without having to worry about breaking anything.
- As was mentioned in other responses, the ability to intentionally commit the code that you want to share with others is substantially different than just saving all versions of the code at 15 minute intervals.  You are no doubt saving off multiple non-working versions of code that you or others will later need to dig through to find the previous good version that you actually need.

It is pretty simple to get a version control system up and running,
particular in an environment as straightforward as this one.  So the investment required isn't very high.  As I mentioned, the backup based system you have now sounds like it could be needlessly complex and potentially fragile.  **You should benefit from the years of investment the community has made in building tools like SVN, Git, or Mercurial to solve exactly the problem of maintaining multiple versions of the software** and providing a good deal of additional capability that is directly useful to developers.

By setting up and using using formal version control, you will develop a valuable set of skills that will serve you well throughout your career. Almost every professional software development environment uses a version control system.  Knowing the ins and outs of how to set up and use a repository will help you over an over again.

I am not familiar with Mercurial, but from what I understand, it is a full blown revision control system.  If you already have some familiarity with it, it might be worth starting to experiment with it as a VCS.

Answer (score 12):

In a **professional** environment where there is code written **you should always have** source control.

There is always the danger of an interview candidate asking what you use for version control and refusing the position because of the lack of a reasonable version control system.

Also... if you happen to be able to hire a professional they might also have a lot harder time understanding and using your current versioning environment.

Comment: This is very weak.  It is unlikely that a shop does not need version control, but if a shop truly does not need version control and a candidate refuses to work for a shop without version control, then it probably is not a good match.  That being said, I don't believe in the existence of shops that don't need version control.

Comment: Good point but I'd say these days source control is just as beneficial on non-professional environments as well.

Answer (score 11):

As other people have said, "now" is always a good time to start using version control. There's so many benefits to using a good version control system it's almost a no brainer.

You mention you use Mercurial. Like other distributed vcs, you can always initialize your own (private) repo and work there. Why not try that? If it starts working for you, it might work for your team. DVCS is all about building from the ground up.

Answer (score 4):

Version control really is one of the most critical pieces of a functional development team. Aside from the standpoint that your code is always backed up, you are exposed to features such as commit messages that help you understand exactly what the person before you (or you yourself) did to a particular file. You can also diff files with previous versions and create tags for particular releases. Tags are a HUGE benefit in that you can basically create a snapshot of version x.x.x of your app's source code. This makes tracking down old bugs much much easier.

Start reading up on different platforms and see what suits your needs best. We used SVN because there were tools integrated into our IDE to leverage SVN. Ironically we do not even use these tools now, we just use Tortoise SVN to check in and check out code.

To answer your question, version control is needed from the moment you write your first line of code.